# Acess the JSON of a Jupyter Noteook While inside of it

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I find that Jupyter notebooks are stored in .json format.

How can I access this (read only) while inside of the notebook itself?

I want to programmatically get the name of the notebook I am currently working in as a string.

EDIT:

Just want to clarify that I know of the solutions using ipynbname and ipyparams, and I am looking for alternate solutions. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

for your particular use case you might want to use a package called `ipyparams`

You can import it at the top of your file and get your file's name as such:

```
import ipyparams
notebook_name = ipyparams.notebook_name
```

Comment: Thanks van. I also see I can do it with ipynbname. But is there another way? Perhaps a way that is a few lines of 'magic' ?

Comment: No problem, I would have thought the filename is in the json structure of the ipynb file but I opened some of my files and couldn't find the name there

Comment: Thanks for checking, too bad its not there